# SIMD the following code

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd

How do I SIMIDize the following code in C (using SIMD intrinsics of course)? I am having trouble understanding SIMD intrinsics and this would help a lot:

```
int sum_naive( int n, int *a )
{
    int sum = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        sum += a[i];
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Which SIMD did you have in mind? SSE2?

Comment: SSE The following intrinsics could be used.__m128i _mm_setzero_si128( )
__m128i _mm_loadu_si128( __m128i *p )
__m128i _mm_add_epi32( __m128i a, __m128i b )(a0+b0, a1+b1, a2+b2, a3+b3)
   void _mm_storeu_si128( __m128i *p, __m128i a )

Comment: Ok, so SSE2. What have you tried?

Comment: int sum_vectorized( int n, int *a )
{
    __m128i sum = _mm_setzero_si128();
 __m128i a = _mm_loadu_si128( __m128i *p)
 for (int i = 0; i<n;i++_)
 {
  sum = _mm_add_epi32( __m128i a+0, __m128i a+1 )
  
 }
 
 
    return 0;
} I am obviously doing something wrong. Quite confused about SSE instructions

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should extend the question with what you tried instead of commenting.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a fairly straightforward implementation (warning: untested code):

```
int32_t sum_array(const int32_t a[], const int n)
{
    __m128i vsum = _mm_set1_epi32(0);       // initialise vector of four partial 32 bit sums
    int32_t sum;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i += 4)
    {
        __m128i v = _mm_load_si128(&a[i]);  // load vector of 4 x 32 bit values
        vsum = _mm_add_epi32(vsum, v);      // accumulate to 32 bit partial sum vector
    }
    // horizontal add of four 32 bit partial sums and return result
    vsum = _mm_add_epi32(vsum, _mm_srli_si128(vsum, 8));
    vsum = _mm_add_epi32(vsum, _mm_srli_si128(vsum, 4));
    sum = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(vsum);
    return sum;
}
```

Note that the input array, `a[]`, needs to be 16 byte aligned, and `n` should be a multiple of 4.

Comment: Couple minor things. _mm_setzero_si128() is better, instruction is faster than RAM reference and not all compilers optimize away set with 0 argument. Also, for horizontal operations, I often see in profiler that it’s faster to store then use scalar code.

Comment: @Soonts: for any reasonable value of n the code before/after the loop is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Isn't a+i faster than &a[i]?

Comment: @Gustavo6046: any half-decent compiler will generate identical code for these two equivalent ways of specifying the same thing. Try it out on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org) if you have any doubts.